# How do i conditionally retry and rescrape the current page in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, and not too impressive with Python. I've got a scraper set up to scrape data from a website, but although I'm using proxies, if the same proxy is used too many times then my request is shown a page telling me I'm visiting too many pages too quickly (HTTP status code 200).

As my scraper see's the page's status code as okay, it doesn't find the needed data and moves on to the next page.

I can determine when these pages are show via HtmlXPathSelector, but how do i signal Scrapy to retry that page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy comes with a built-in [`retry` middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry).  You could subclass it and override the [`process_response`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response) method to include a check to see if the page that is telling you that you're visiting too many pages too quickly is showing up

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying all night to see how it's done, but can't work out how i go about overriding the method mentioned? I've added a `RetryMiddleware(object)` class with a `process_response` method so far and referenced it from my settings, but `self.retry_http_codes` is not found from the class above. Do i need to change `object` to something else above?

Comment: @john inheritance is a whole other issue http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance, after inheriting you should be calling the original `Retry` classes methods,you also have to register your new retry middleware, scrapy expalins how to do that in the docs

Comment: I had a play with that also but couldn't find the correct class to pass into it. For example i make a class: `RetryMiddlewareSubclass(RetryMiddleware)`, but it tells me RetryMiddleware is not defined, I've tried a few different combinations but none have worked that i can find. As soon as i figure out what to pass into the class i should be okay... or am i completely off course here?

Comment: @john you are right, you have to import `RetryMiddleware`. `from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry import RetryMiddleware`. `RetryMiddlewareSubclass(RetryMiddleware)`